# No partitions when installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, boot-repair

I am trying to create a dual boot for Ubuntu, with Windows 10 already installed. In the install Ubuntu installation type I get:

[image]

If I click <kbd>Install now</kbd> for `/dev/sda` I get:

[image]

So I tried looking at Gparted and I get: 
[image]

Now when I click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> I get this:
[image]

When I click <kbd>Ignore</kbd> I get this: 
[image]

Also I used boot-repair. I have a pastebin output from it. If that would be helpful I will put that link as well.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: @Anderson: Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1056183/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new unallocated space(let's say 50 gb for Ubuntu) on Windows 10 using Disk Managment. After that try with the Live Usb Option the same step that you did to install Ubuntu. If you want to make different partitions then select Something else and follow this guide [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) . If not then choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and Ubuntu automatically will do it for you.

Comment: What do I do about the partitions I already created. Something wrong happened the first time I created them using the Installation step. I created 2 partitions from /dev/sda5 to create /dev/sda5 as swap area and /dev/sda7 as ext4 filesystem area.

Comment: If you have created 4 partition for /root /home/ /boot /swap, let's say /boot is in dev/sda6/  then you need to select this boot partition under Device for boot loader installation, click Install now and the partition will be formatted and will be ready for the installation process.